# VB code to Objective C

Tags: objective-c, vb.net

Im new to coding in Xcode and using Objective C. But I have an old code from a project written in VB I wound like to convert to Objective C.

Here is the code:

```
Private Sub VitalityButton4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles VitalityButton4.Click
    If txtWebURL.Text <> Nothing Then
        Try
            Dim wc As New WebClient
            wc.Proxy = Nothing

            Dim ST As String = wc.DownloadString("http://isup.me/" & txtWebURL.Text)
            If ST.ToLower.Contains("it's not just you!") Then
                txtWebStatus.Text = "Down!"
            Else
                txtWebStatus.Text = "Up!"
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            cse()
        End Try
    End If
End Sub
```

Im making a Mac OS X application, not iOS.

Comment: what about to do it line-by-line?

Comment: `On Error Resume Next`

Answer (score 3):

There is no magic way to convert VB code to Obj-C, you'll have to do it line by line, which means you will need to learn Objective-C.

[Here is a decent place to start learning](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/an-introduction-to-objective-c).  Apple also provides a lot of resources.